# jQuery Sortable plugin seems to break serialize method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a simple AJAX form that allows users to reorder items and operate on them at the same time.  I'm using the jQuery Sortable plugin and that all seems to work well -- however, I also added in the `.serialize()` method to pass along additional form information.  When I click the submit button *without reordering* everything gets passed just fine.  If I reorder an item, all of the other items are sent along but the form values of the reordered item is ignored.

Here's my jQuery:

```
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
  ui.children().each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width());
  });
  return ui;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sortable tbody").sortable({ 
    helper: fixHelper,
    opacity: 0.6, 
    update: function(){
      $('#savemessage').html('<p>Click <em>Update/Reorder</em> to save</p>');
      }
  });
  $('#button').click(function(event){
    var order = $("#sortable tbody").sortable("serialize");
    order += "&" + $("form[name=dashboard]").serialize();
    order += "&crudtype=update_dashboard";
    $('#savemessage').html('<p>Saving changes...</p>');
    $.post("/account/crud",order,function(theResponse){
      $('#savemessage').html(theResponse);
    });
  });
});
```

My HTML is created through PHP but here's the rendered output:

```
<table class="data" id="sortable">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <form name="dashboard" id="dashboard">
    <tr class="odd" id="field_10">
      <td class="handle"><a href="#">Favorites</a></td>
      <td><div class="inline_checkbox"><input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="dashboard_email"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard and Email</span><input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="dashboard" checked="checked"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard</span><input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="email"><span class="boxlabel">Email</span><input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="off"><span class="boxlabel">Off</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" id="field_1">
      <td class="handle"><a href="#">Process Tasks</a></td>
      <td><div class="inline_checkbox"><input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="dashboard_email" checked="checked"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard and Email</span><input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="dashboard"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard</span><input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="email"><span class="boxlabel">Email</span><input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="off"><span class="boxlabel">Off</span></div></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update/Reorder Items" class="form-submit-table" id="button">
```

So for example, if I just click submit and `alert(order);` in the jQuery after building the querystring, I see the POSTed data from both items.  But if I drag one over the other to reorder them, I only see the data from the item that was not moved.

Comment: why do you need field_1 and field_10, can't you just re order using the names of the radio selections?

Comment: No, that's necessary for the sortable plugin.  The problem is that reordering evidently takes the inputs out of the equation when the serialize method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html was not valid and it was messing up jQuery being able to find the elements.

The form tag should be outside the table. I edited your html.

```
<form name="dashboard" id="dashboard">
<table class="data" id="sortable">

     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
     </tr>      
    </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd" id="field_10">
      <td class="handle"><a href="#">Favorites</a></td>
      <td><div class="inline_checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="dashboard_email"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard and Email</span>
            <input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="dashboard" checked="checked"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard</span>
            <input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="email"><span class="boxlabel">Email</span>
            <input type="radio" name="favorites" class="box_inline" value="off"><span class="boxlabel">Off</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" id="field_1">
      <td class="handle"><a href="#">Process Tasks</a></td>
      <td><div class="inline_checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="dashboard_email" checked="checked"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard and Email</span>
        <input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="dashboard"><span class="boxlabel">Dashboard</span>
        <input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="email"><span class="boxlabel">Email</span>
        <input type="radio" name="process_tasks" class="box_inline" value="off"><span class="boxlabel">Off</span></div></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
</form>
```

This allowed the radio button elements to be found after sorting the rows.

Comment: Sure enough -- can't believe I missed that.  Thanks very much!